# Function pointer to a template class

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I need some help on a strange mix between function pointers and templates...

My target :

You have a class : `template<typename B> class A`, and A instanciate a B member. Now I want to acces B getter/setter.

I tried this :

```
class B_example
{
public:
    B_example(int v):m_var(v){}
    int getVar() { return m_var; }
    void setVar(int v) { m_var = v; }

private:
    int m_var;
};


template<typename B> class A
{
public:
    A():m_b(B(5))
    {
        get = &m_b.getVar;
        set = &m_b.setVar;
    }

    int (B::*get)();
    void (B::*set)(int);

private:
    B m_b;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A<B_example> A_instance;
    B_example B_instance(5);


    int a = (A_instance.get*)();

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Thank's for any help.

Alexandre

Comment: why not a generalized callback using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: Because sometimes I need void(int), sometimes int(void), sometime float(int), sometime Cv::Size(void). I don'know function profile...

Comment: [here](http://ideone.com/4tDsvL)'s a `std::function` rewrite, but what you're trying to do is not very clear. If you're just trying to access the fields, do that. Apart from that, I'd recommend you the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)

Comment: "Because sometimes I need void(int), sometimes int(void), sometime float(int), sometime Cv::Size(void). I don'know function profile.." that would take some metaprogramming and it still doesn't explain what you're actually trying to do. Can you think of a concise useful example?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/AltranResearchMedica/ARAM)

TagDetector instantiate IROIDetector, and n times ITag.

But I need from the outside of library to acces to every parameters of LineFitting or EdgeDetector or ... (derived from IROIDetector), and to every parameters of HammingTag or StandardTag or LocalThreshTag ... (derived from ITag)

Comment: can you formulate the task in a domain-independent language? as in, some object-oriented modeling way, and simple?

Comment: I talk with other develloper, and a Java devvlloper give me an "answer" :

I need reflection on setter/getter of class B_example.

Comment: ok. Check out the link to [picojson_serializer](https://github.com/d-led/picojson_serializer) and the mentioned within [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). That's why it's important to know what you're actually trying to do

Answer (score 1):

First, fix the syntax errors:

```
get = &B::getVar;
set = &B::setVar;
```

Then, the member-function pointer needs to be called on an object. Without knowing the purpose of these strange pointers, I can't guess what you want to do here. Maybe you want to call on `B_instance`:

```
int a = (B_instance.*A_instance.get)();
```

Or maybe you want to call it on the `m_b` object within `A_instance`; but you can't do that because it's private. If that's the case, you probably just want regular member functions, rather than weird function pointers

```
int get() {return m_b.getVar();}
void set(int v) {m_b.setVar(v);}
```

Comment: If `m_b` were public, then `A_instance.m_b.*A_instance.get` would work. Makes me feel sorry for C++ parser writers :)

Comment: My problem is that B is an implementation with 5 parameter, of an interface IB, but I have C where is an implementation with 7 parameters, of IB, and so on...

I want to let user acces to this parameter, but B have to stay private in A.

So i want to store tuple with : parameter name, get function, set function, so user can easy loop through list of tuple, and get/set parameters I allowed.

Answer (score 0):

These:

```
get = &m_b.getVar;
set = &m_b.setVar;
```

Should be:

```
get = &B::getVar;
set = &B::setVar;
```

And `(A_instance.get*)()` should be `(B_instance.*A_instance.get)()`.